# Datepicker Angularjs startWeek on Monday

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

I've a problem with angular md-datepicker. It's start by default on Sunday, but I need to start on Monday.

I've been tried to add an option to the controller, but it doesn't work. Anyone can help me please?

This is the code:

```
 $scope.dateOptions = {
  formatYear: 'yy',
  showWeeks: false,      
  firstDayOfWeek  : 1
};
<md-datepicker ng-model="desdeDate" md-placeholder="Enter date" options="dateOptions"></md-datepicker>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use following code to configure first day of week in md-date

```
 angular.module('MyApp').controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myDate = new Date();


}).config(function($mdDateLocaleProvider) {

  // Can change week display to start on Monday.
  $mdDateLocaleProvider.firstDayOfWeek = 1;
  // Optional.

  });
```

Below is link for working example.

[Link for example](http://codepen.io/kuldeeppvithlani/pen/vKGVKZ)

You need to change start day of week using $mdDateLocaleProvider.